# Ext.Net this.Direct() function not recognized

Tags: c#, razor, ext.net, asp.net-mvc-5.2

I intalled Ext.Net 2.5 with razor.
it work fine.
but has error in this function:

```
 public ActionResult UpdateTimeStamp()
    {
        DatabaseContext db = new DatabaseContext();
        var ds = db.Users.Where(user => user.Name == "mehdi");

        X.Msg.Notify("The Server Time is: ", DateTime.Now.ToLongTimeString()).Show();

        return this.Direct();

    }
```

`this.Direct();` not recognized. why?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Direct" extension method belongs to the Ext.Net.MVC namespace.

Is there this statement in the controller?

```
using Ext.Net.MVC;
```